# How to read this JSON with Java?

Tags: java, json

I have this `JSON` code and I don't know how to read `poster_path`. I know there's a lot of tutorials but none of them worked for me, it would be really great if someone help me.

```
{  
   "movie_results":[  
      {  
         "adult":false,
         "backdrop_path":"/j9XKiZrVeViAixVRzCta7h1VU9W.jpg",
         "genre_ids":[  
            80,
            18
         ],
         "id":278,
         "original_language":"en",
         "original_title":"The Shawshank Redemption",
         "overview":"Framed in the 1940s for the double murder of his wife and her lover, upstanding banker Andy Dufresne begins a new life at the Shawshank prison, where he puts his accounting skills to work for an amoral warden. During his long stretch in prison, Dufresne comes to be admired by the other inmates -- including an older prisoner named Red -- for his integrity and unquenchable sense of hope.",
         "poster_path":"/9O7gLzmreU0nGkIB6K3BsJbzvNv.jpg",
         "release_date":"1994-09-23",
         "title":"The Shawshank Redemption",
         "video":false,
         "vote_average":8.6,
         "vote_count":11374,
         "popularity":30.881
      }
   ],
   "person_results":[  

   ],
   "tv_results":[  

   ],
   "tv_episode_results":[  

   ],
   "tv_season_results":[  

   ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried already?

Comment: Use jackson api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JSONObject:

```
JSONOBject json = new JSONObject(string);
String posterPath = json.getJSONArray("movie_results")
                    .getJSONObject(index)
                    .getString("poster_path");
```

Comment: may i ask what's the `index` from  `.getJSONObject(index)` ?

Comment: in this case 0, generally it should be assigned by you variable as well as string should be raw json